# What does a line look like in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2?$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I have a hard time going between points and lines in projective space. For example,  if I want to consider the line $x = 0,$ then I know this corresponds to the point $$[0 : y : z] = [0 : 1 : z/y] \rightarrow [0: 1 : 0]$$ as $y \rightarrow \infty.$ I know this is the line at infinity, but I don't know what this looks like as an actual line, if that makes any sense. Can anyone help me visualize what a line looks like in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2?$

Comment: It's a copy of $\Bbb CP^1$: if you have the point $[0:y:z]$ in $\Bbb CP^2$, then $y$ and $z$ can't both be zero at the same time, which means that $[y:z]$ defines a perfectly good point in $\Bbb CP^1$.

Comment: As a personal intuition, I think a line in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ as a real line with more geometry in it. For example, two lines in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ meet in one point as two (non-parallel) real lines would do in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Many mathematicians also draw them just like real lines.